# Change icons in Sandcastle

Tags: icons, sandcastle

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the icons in the `TOC Treeview` (the purple books) in `SandCastle` compiled chm files ?

I've searched the `SandCastle` install folder but could not find these particular icons.

I'm now thinking that maybe they are native to chm documents...

Comment: David,

I assume they are native to windows help, because they are in every windows help file I've ever seen going back to Windows 95. I'm pretty sure they predate compiled html  (chm) files.